# How to Upload a file to Apache using PHP file

Tags: smartface.io

I have downloaded the Upload Download sample from Smartface.io but I do not see that it references a PHP postfile. Can Smartface upload to an Apache server using a PHP file? Can you provide an example or lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

Smartface App Stuido only uses JavaScript for client side. But you can use any kind of server technology which supports SOAP or JSON restful.

You can read more about for upload download with Parse;

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/data-network/rest-services/